# Adding Charting.Chart in PowerPoint.Slide

Tags: c#, vb.net, powerpoint, office-interop

Just wondering if it's possible to Add System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart into Interop.PowerPoint.Slide object?

The idea is to use Charting.Chart instead of Excel.Charts in PowerPoint addin automation.

One solution is to Save Charting.Chart as image on file system and then add that image in Slide.Shapes collection.

But is there any better approach to do this?

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Theoretically it would be possible by "wrapping" the object in an OLE ActiveX control supported by the Office (Powerpoint) document interface - which is basically what VSTO does for the WinForms controls it supports for Excel and Word. Practically, this is apparently not very easy... Search the msdn VSTO forum as there were some discussions there maybe ten years ago on the topic with MSFT folks who understood the "under the covers" mechanics.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister, appreciate that. Let hope I find something from the forum.

Comment: I've turned up the following which may help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4282a65c-ccd7-4fd4-a56c-75f84615fff6/embedding-active-x-control-in-office-application-using-vsto-2005?forum=vsto, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71a75dc4-dcea-454a-9e4a-011a2f811994/vsto-activex-and-powerpoint?forum=vsto, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1997b2c1-9806-4334-b99f-77f3333f8189/activex-control-development-for-ms-word?forum=vsto, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/11/25/using-managed-controls-as-activex-controls/ ...

Comment: and... https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/wrapping-a-net-user-control-as-an-activex, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/03/13/activex-controls-in-vsto-solutions/

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister for the interest. I'll check those post in detail once I get back to the same task.

Comment: @CindyMeister, can you please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450008/powerpoint-shapes-addoleobject-throws-error-hresult-e-fail