# PowerPoint Shapes.AddOLEObject Throws Error HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: c#, vb.net, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

Following the guidelines from [this link](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/wrapping-a-net-user-control-as-an-activex), I've wrapped a user control as an ActiveX component. Build the code successfully, and I can confirm that the COM component is registered in Windows registry.

Class name mentioned in registry is "MyChartsControl.UserControl1".

After that I try to add my ActiveX Wrapped user control in PowerPoint Slide object using following code:

```
powerpointSlideObject.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 111, 222, ClassName:="MeridiaChartsControl.UserControl1")
```

OR using the ProgId:

```
powerpointSlideObject.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 111, 222, ClassName:="ActiveXTestLibrary.UserControl")
```

The code throws the exception given below:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Though following code works fine on same slide object if I add picture:

```
powerpointSlideObject.Shapes.AddPicture("d:\\temp\\image1.png", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 400, 150)
```

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: E_FAIL is a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting.  At some point PowerPoint just stops trying to guess what you're trying to do and throws up its hands.  UserControl is not an OLE object.  OLE is pretty dead in general and only survives in the Office object model.  Mostly because they couldn't remove it without risking breaking old projects. .NET made no attempt to implement it.

Comment: I seem to remember that when doing something similar, but for Excel and using [Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264), that it is important to not use the `AnyCPU` platform and instead either use `x86` or `x64`.